# Razor not so smart detecting C# from html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to print this html in a view:

```
@foreach (string indices in Model.Indices)
{
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        Response.Write("<tr>");
    }      
                                  
    Response.Write("<td><span class='select'>@Html.CheckBox('nome',false)</span>)");  @indices Response.Write("</td>");

    if (counter > 4) 
    {
        Response.Write("</tr>"); 
    }                
}
```

This will print the html markup which I want to create.

I know I could only write the html but Razor is complaining that I am not closing the foreach.

This was my first try:

```
@foreach (string indices in Model.Indices)
{
    if (counter == 1)
    {
        <tr>
    }      
                                  
    <td><span class='select'>@Html.CheckBox('nome',false)</span> @indices </td>

    @if (counter > 4) 
    {
        </tr>
    }                
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some error details?

Comment: It may be getting confused because you are potentially not closing the `tr` so it thinks you need to close that before you end the foreach... Certainly the line `@if (counter > 4)` looks wrong since I can't see you resetting the counter (I assume that is a magic variable created by the foreach?) so on the 5th, 6th, etc. counter then you will be closing the tr without having opened any more...

Comment: where are you increment counter? It seems to me, that <tr> and </tr> should be outer to foreach statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor requires that HTML tags be well-formed; otherwise, it wouldn't know when to go back to code context.

You can bypass this restriction by prefixing the line with `@:`.

However, the correct way to do this is to group your collection into a collection of groups of 4 items, and use a nested `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

If i right understand what do you want (Do you want to display first four elements from Model.Indices?), you should move your  and  tags out from your foreach. Something like this:

```
<tr>
@{var counter = 1;}
@foreach (string indice in indices)
    {
        if(counter>4)
        {break;}
        <td><span class='select'>@Html.CheckBox("nome", false)</span> @indice </td>
        counter++;
    }
</tr>
```

Comment: You were right. I completely rewrite my answer and undelete it.